# Random Voronoi percolation to SLE($\kappa$), for which $\kappa$?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

Random Voronoi percolation is described in ["The critical probability for random Voronoi percolation in the plane is 1/2"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410336v2.pdf) .

They mention that Schramm and Benjamini, showed a form of conformal invariance. I am wondering, if we have any evidence that Random Voronoi should have an SLE as its scaling limit eg. numerical? Do we also know which $\kappa$?

Comment: The book *Percolation* (Bollabas & Riordan) has a chapter on "Random Voronoi Percolation." Not sure if they discuss your question...